# "IndexError: string index out of range" when injecting SQL statements from a list via for-loop

Tags: python, csv, psycopg2, index-error

I try to read a column of a .csv file into a database with psycopg2.
The data from the column in the .csv comes in form:
<other_col>   genres
<...>       Rock|Pop|Metallic Doom Rock|...

I first read these values row-wise and split "|", them and append everything to one list where I remove duplicates with set.
My input file needed a little formatting and have to be unique, thus I transformed the values into a list(set(data))).

When for-looping over said list to build SQL statements that should implant the values, I get "IndexError: string index out of range" and I don't understand why, since I read elements from a list and not a single string. Can someone give me a hint, where I fail?

```py
test = csv_to_dict("artists.csv", "\t")    #this is a predefined function, that just reads csv.dictReader and the csv-file is tab-separated.

genre_list =[]
for row in test:
    genres = (row['genres'])
    genres = (genres.split(sep="|"))    # this is to "clean" and generate list with unique genres
    for p in genres:
        genre_list.append(p.title())
genre_list = list(set(genre_list))
genre_list.sort()

cur = sql_con.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT INTO Genre (GenreName) VALUES(%s);' # here I expect genre from genre_list to be inserted @ %s
for genre in genre_list:
    cur.execute(sql, genre)
sql_con.commit()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../IngestData.py", line 76, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql, t)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: The error message is consistent with `genre` (or `t`) being an empty string.  Print the value before executing the insert statement to confirm.

Comment: Oh I know that there is an empty value in the list, but I did not know, that python can't insert an empty value. Thank you!

Comment: It is possible to insert an empty string, but you need to pass it (or any other value in fact) inside a tuple: so `cursor.execute(sql, (genre,))`.

Comment: 1) @snakecharmerb or a `list` or a `dict` see [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). 2) The code in your traceback does not match the code in your example: `cur.execute(sql, t)` vs `cur.execute(sql, genre)` 3) The issue is that `psycopg2`  when using `%` is assuming the values are a sequence. A string by itself is a sequence and what you are seeing is: `s = ''  s[0]  IndexError: string index out of range`. This means the data that did go in was done as single letters of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error due to `x=(1)` *not* creating a list with a single value.  To create a single-valued list/tuple, you need the trailing comma:

```
foo=(1)
print(foo)
Out[7]: 1

bar=(1,)
print(bar)
Out[9]: (1,)
```